# If $\xi_\mu$ is a Killing vector is it true that its contravariant representation $\xi^\mu$ also is a Killing vector?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields

**Question**
I have worked on an exercise and proved that
$$
\nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu} \xi_{\mu}=0
$$

i.e. that $\xi_\mu$ is a Killing vector. Now I wonder if it therefore follows that the contravariant repsentation $\xi^\mu$ also is a Killing vector?

**My own attempt trying to prove that it is true**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu} \xi_{\mu}
&=
\nabla_{\mu}(g_{\nu \nu} \xi^{\nu}) +\nabla_{\nu}( g_{\mu \mu} \xi^{\mu})
\\
&= g_{\nu \nu} \nabla_{\mu}( \xi^{\nu}) +g_{\mu \mu} \nabla_{\nu}(  \xi^{\mu}) 
\end{aligned}
$$

but here I believe I've already severely abused the notation by having more than two indices of the same kind and furthermore do not know where to go.

Comment: why did you use the same index multiple times if you know it's wrong?

Comment: @fqq I thought it was wrong but wanted to confirm that it was wrong to do so

Comment: The first question you have to answer is, what is your definition of Killing vector for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise the indices as follows,
$$  g^{\mu \lambda} g^{\nu \rho} ( \nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu} \xi_{\mu}) = 0 \\
\nabla^{\lambda}\xi^{\rho} + \nabla^{\rho} \xi^{\lambda} = 0 \  ,
$$
which is equivalent. This is just requiring the Lie derivative of the *inverse* metric to vanish, which is the correct way to think about the killing vector equation with components $\xi^{\mu}$.
This seems like what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. This might just be rather meaningless semantics but in other words when you find that something is a Killing vector you are talking about the complete object and it does not matter if you found that property by examining it's covariant or contravariant *representation*?

Comment: @MattiasJohnson yes, I think that's the right gist of it. We often refer to a killing vector (field) with both $\xi^{\mu}$ and $\xi_{\mu}$ , despite the latter being a killing *covector* (field), simply because we can relate the two with the metric $\xi_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} \xi^{\nu}$. Both equations are equivalent and represent the same isometries of the metric.

Answer (score 1):

You can't lower the index like that, use $\xi_\nu=g_{\nu\alpha}\xi^\alpha$ instead, and you will see that $\nabla_\mu\xi^\nu+\nabla_\nu\xi^\mu=0$ does not hold. That equation is also wrong by construction, as you can't have the same index up and down if it is not summed.

Comment: Okay so my method was wrong which I suspected, but do you anything regarding the question? If $\xi_\mu$ is a Killing vector does that mean that $\xi^\mu$ also is a Killing vector? from this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78883/190074 it seems that a vector is a Killing vector in both its representations but not sure about it and would like to get a clear cut answer

Comment: Actually, $\xi_\mu$ is not a vector, but the covariant components of the vector $\xi$. $\xi^\mu$ are its contravariant components.